# Vim - loop through files in cope

Tags: vim

how can I lop through buffers in quickfix list `:copen` and make some actions with it.

Or any alternative way to put those files to args list and I can use argsdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a vim plugin that suits my need completely which is [vim-qargs](https://github.com/henrik/vim-qargs). The idea behind is almost the same with @Ingo.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the loop yourself:

```
for file in ['foo.txt', 'bar.txt']
   execute 'edit' fnameescape(file)
   " Your processing here.
endfor
```

Or if you already have all files loaded in Vim, use `:bufdo` and execute your commands conditionally, based on whether the buffer (or buffer number with `bufnr('')`) is in your list:

```
bufdo if index(['foo.txt', 'bar.txt'], bufname('')) != -1) | execute ... | endif
```

**Edit**: Now that I understand you want to iterate over the files in the *quickfix list* (the one you see when you do `:copen`, you can get their buffer numbers via `map(getqflist(), 'v:val.bufnr')`. Still need to avoid processing the same buffer multiple times, though.

Comment: This is actually not what I'm looking for. I don't know exactly what files I'm gonna edit, I just want it take the files listed in `:cope`. 
So it will be not efficient that everytime we get files in vim cope and then remember the name and then write function to do it. Sometimes, it's just a replacement

Comment: @Vdt I didn't get that part initially; please use the available markup (like you did in your comment), and beware of typos in your question.